# Find the probability of a lottery prize

Tags: probability

The state of Oregon wishes to design a new lottery game with the following rules:

1.Each ticket costs $5$  dollars

2.There will be three prizes: $10$ dollars, $100$ dollars and $1000 $ dollars

3.The probability of the $10$ dollars prize will be $20\%$.

4.The probability of the $100$ dollars prize will be $1\%$

5.Ten thousand tickets will be sold each month.

What should the probability for the $1000$ dollars prize be set at, if the state would like, on average, to earn $10,000 $ dollars each month?

10000 is the average profit of a month, total income of a month is $50000$, total prize of a month is $10\times 0.2\times 10000+100\times 0.01\times 10000= 30000$, this isn't include the $1000$ prize

so: $10000=50000-30000-1000\times x\times 10000$, $x=0.001$

can someone check this right or not? Thanks

Comment: The answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have the right answer.

Total Prize: $10000*(0.001*1000 + 0.2*10 + 0.01*100)$ = 40 000 dollars

Total Revenue: $10000*5$ = 50000 dollars

Profit = Total Revenue - Total Prize
= $10000